# How get share count Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need share count Facebook. For example with this URL: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=1395527550740242&story_fbid=1429749413984722                                  It contains "2" share count...
                                                               Do not need to offer such options:  graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.mashable.com
I was wrong share counts with the site facebook.com, as in the above example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the general info about the Facebook post you can do it this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID_POSTID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you want to return the array of shares use this approach:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/POSTID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=sharedposts
```

Check the output [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1395527550740242_1429749413984722%20&version=v2.2&#_=__) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1429749413984722%3Ffields%3Dsharedposts&version=v2.2&#_=__).

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz Pawlik!

Comment: Write the first option which only POSTID, and returns an array sharedposts